# Transaction doesn't seem to work in Spring Declarative Transaction Mode

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, declarative

I am trying to implement declarative transaction management in a Spring+Struts+Hibernate setup.
This is a part of my applicationcontext.xml

```
<property>
  <props>
    <prop key="foodoo*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-FooException</prop>
  </props>
</property>
```

I have defined two public methods in my FooService class -> UpdateFoo, foodooTest
and two private methods (which have the update logic) -> Test1 and Test2

The call goes like:

```
UpdateFoo->foodooTest->Test1
                     ->Test2
```

(foodooTest should trigger the transaction)
I create the bean

```
FooService fooService = (FooService)context.getBean("fooService");
//and call
fooService.UpdateFoo();
```

Test2 throws FooException and hence I expect the transaction to roll back. But it does not. Commit happens in each Test1 and Test2 (until the exception).
I use Hibernate getHibernateTemplate.Merge() for the updates. My db engine is InnoDB.

I'm not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: You should post more relevant suff: spring configuration and the methods that trigger the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring rolls back transactions on exception only if the custom exception extends `RuntimeException`.  Make sure `FooException` extends `RuntimeException`([reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)):

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework's transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. (Errors will also - by default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default configuration.

Based on your comment, here are 2 more things to check: 1) make sure you have a platform transaction manager configured.  Example:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Additionally, if you want to use annotations for transactions, you need to config that too:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: okay, my problem is not really a rollback (i think that is in control). My problem is commit happens in Test1 and Test2 (I can see that in DB) even before I go ahead and throw the FooException.

Comment: Yes, It is configured. Also, if I add 'UpdateFoo' to the application configuration, the transaction works as expected. (I am making calls to UpdateFoo from the struts action in both the cases.

Comment: That means that the Spring config you are using for your testing doesn't match the Spring config for your app.  Make those two match up as best as possible.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I am working on my local box and making updates and testing everything on that. My concern -> If I add the Service_Call method (which I call from Struts action class) to the config that defines transaction rules, transaction seems to work as expected. However, if instead of adding Service_Call to that config, I add a proxy method Foo to the Config and call Foo from Service_Call method, transaction doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I meant: if you're running a test outside of your Spring app's config (e.g., using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`), then that could account for the different behavior.  If you're changing how the method is called inside your app, that's different.  Please update your question to reflect the full config you're trying to debug.